# What is an enzymatic reaction for which a detailed tertiary structure showing all ligands is available on the PDB?

Tags: biochemistry, cheminformatics, enzymes

This is a follow-up to my earlier question here [How do I obtain a 3D MOLFILE for the lactose synthase structure, especially the catalytic center?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158258/how-do-i-obtain-a-3d-molfile-for-the-lactose-synthase-structure-especially-the) about the lactate synthase. I am using the lactate synthase and the paper I referenced only as an example. But sadly, it's not a great example because the authors have not submitted their (predicted) model of the exact ligand configuration during the critical catalytic step when actually the Galactose is added at beta-configuration to the Glucose.

I would like to find another example which of an enzyme, perhaps involving a metal ion too, for which we have pretty exact configurations submitted to PDB that show how exactly the reactants are aligned to create a specific reaction with a specific stereo-configuration, so we can see why exactly the reaction occurs on that atom and in that direction.

I thought the glycolysis pathway should be very well understood by now, but when I went to UniProt KB looking for the hexokinase, I do not see any tertiary structure model with any ligand. Besides, the glycolysis is a catabolic pathway, and I'd like to show an anabolic reaction, although if I remember correctly, many of the glycolysis steps are reversible.

Appreciate if you can point me to better examples that have lots of "snapshots" of the reaction publicly available.

**EDIT comment:**

This is what I am looking for: an anabolic enzymatic reaction, ideally with a metal ion involved in the reaction complex, and for which -- unlike in the case of the lactate synthase -- we have snapshots for the critical step of the reaction: the alignment of two ligands which get bonded into a single stereo-isomer. There is nothing dumb, nothing too broad, and **nothing opinion-based about this question**. The truth is, it's hard to find one by just trial and error fishing on PDB or UniProt.

Comment: How would you tell if something is *best* studied?

Comment: How do you define «best studied», what threshold(s) do you use to define «this is good enough»? Hunting for multiple X-ray snapshots of one reaction/type of reaction with enzymes reads like establishing a trajectory like Bürgi & Dunitz pioneered (the later recently embarked for his last way). So «Time-resolved structural studies of protein reaction dynamics: a smorgasbord of X-ray approaches» by Westenhoff *et al.* in *Acta Cryst.* (2010) **A**66, 207–219 ([doi 10.1107/S0108767309054361](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108767309054361), open access) may offer an entry about these bigger molecules.

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks for the paper reference, which sadly does not discuss any of the kinds of reactions I am looking for, just generally tells why it might not be easy but that it is the right thing. Not sure about all this negativity and going off on the word "best". But I added that comment to my original question.

Comment: Do people get crystal structures of the enzyme bound to its actual substrate? I was under the impression that it's easier to get the structure of a complex with a competitive inhibitor.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow - I have added a comment on your other question. The comments here are not intended to be negative, they are intended to get to the heart of the matter within the site's guidelines.

Comment: Following up on @orthocresol , it is very difficult to determine structures of wild-type enzymes with substrates except at cryo temperatures because the substrates react to products more quickly than any structural data collection method. More often you will see structures with inhibitors that mimic the proposed transition state or substrates bound to inactive variants of the enzyme. Some people generate computational models of the substrate in the wild-type active site and maybe even simulate the reaction, but those structures/simulations don't go to PDB usually.

Comment: @Andrew, I'd love to have even a predicted best guess model, but as you say, they don't usually go into the PDB. But where might they go? In the original lactose synthase paper I started with they have a model, but they didn't submit it to PDB and the authors are unreachable to try to get the model they had 20 years ago.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130172/discussion-on-question-by-gunther-schadow-what-is-an-enzymatic-reaction-with-det).

Comment: @KarstenTheis I appreciate your support vote to re-open but I do not appreciate your edit and comment, they are just more useless formal Rechthaberei. There is everything very exact about a stereo-isomer selective synthesis. And you accused me of "yelling" elsewhere, I am not yelling, I am insisting on the truth. The close reason for this question is a lie.

Comment: The title needs to be edited as it is confusing and a possible cause for the closure. Ambiguous questions are often bound to be closed because the appropriate/best answer would not be clear. In this case the subject of the post is interesting but the question as written seems another, creating confusion. The question might be "are there enzyme crystal structures that show a reagent positioned to undergo a particular reaction mechanism (pathway)". I would suggest the OP *at least* edit the title to reflect the objective of the post...

Comment: Please note that comments critical of others are like screaming into the wind. You have little to nothing to gain and much to lose from them. Instead the best approach here is usually to try to address individuals using their handles (@name) to seek clarification or/and to edit your post in an attempt to address criticism.

Comment: Sometimes, the «click and mouse push» GUI of the databases are only a subset of possibilities to query a database. I recall this from trainings for Beilstein (when moderated by Beilstein institute and MDL) *vs.* access with keywords from the CLI (like STN/Télésystèms Questel) which requests *a different* (like in «complementary») training.  Perhaps the staff members of the databases in question are more likely to help you to identify a «good system» with «good coverage of experimental data».  There are some wizards in these techniques ...